Plot sparse matrix in Pyqtgraph
I have a large sparse matrix and would like to plot it using pyqtgraph. At the moment I am just converting the matrix into a full matrix with the obvious drawback of large memory consumption. Is there a more elegant way of plotting a sparse 2D array using pyqtgraph?

This question is similar to: python matplotlib plot sparse matrix pattern. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
